# Removing item from bpy.app.driver_namespace

Tags: python, drivers

Was wondering if there is a less vigorous way of removing an item from the driver namespace, perhaps using `pop()` or `popitem()`?

```
import bpy

dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dnc = dns.copy()

# clear dns
dns.clear()

#remake with any key beginning with "ST_" removed

for k, v in dnc.items():
    if k.startswith("ST_"):
        continue
    dns[k] = v
```

---

#### Edit

Looks like `dns.update(...)` is the go:

```
D.update([E, ]**F) -> None.  Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
If E is present and has a .keys() method, then does:  for k in E: D[k] = E[k]
If E is present and lacks a .keys() method, then does:  for k, v in E: D[k] = v
In either case, this is followed by: for k in F:  D[k] = F[k]
```

which gives me:

```
import bpy

dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dnc = {k:v for (k, v) in dns.items() if k.startswith("ST_")}

dns.update(dnc)
```

Both of these are ok for a 'startswith search', but seem overkill if I know the name of the item I want to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
del bpy.app.driver_namespace['driverFunc']
```

Comment: Lol as simple as that.